# SMTP.Send() returns after (or during) an email sending session?

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, mailmessage

This vb.net code seems to work *ONLY* if run... and I keep the program open for an additional 5-10 secs AFTER I see the "email sent" message.  If I instead wait 0-1 secs, and then close the prg, the email goes nowhere.

Does SMTP.Send() return AFTER the email is completely sent... or just when the email BEGINS to go out?  (Sometimes the email body and/or file attachment might be 10k long, and take a while.)

```
Dim myMailMessage As New Net.Mail.MailMessage()
myMailMessage.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromEmail)
myMailMessage.To.Add(toEmail)
myMailMessage.Subject = strSubject
myMailMessage.Body = strBody
myMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True

Dim SMTP As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
SMTP.Port = 587
SMTP.EnableSsl = True
SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmail, password)
SMTP.Send(myMailMessage)
call MsgBox("Email is completely done sending")
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx

It's not an asynchronous call, so it only returns after the e-mail has been sent.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding; if it is blocking doesn't that mean as soon as 'Email is completely done sending' appears, it has completed?  If so, why does he have to wait additional seconds after he see the email sent msg?

Comment: Exactly.  Could SMTP.Send() somehow mistakenly be returning "too soon"?  (Email might take 10 secs to truly, fully be sent.  But maybe Send() is incorrectly returning as "done" in 5 seconds?)